# Building documentation with interactive examples in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: notebooks, documentation

There are interactive examples in the documentation in Wolfram Mathematica. Thus to compile them we just need <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I want to develop such examples for functions from my own package, how can I do this?

---

Thanks  a lot for comments..I use W.  Workbench 2.0 to build documentation. But here is the problem, while building, even the examples like NumericalAnalysis it failed with errors:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\NumericalAnalysis\docbuild.xml:132: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\NumericalAnalysis\docbuild.xml:97: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\WolframWorkbench\2.0\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\10\1.cp\MathematicaSource\DocumentationBuild\SystemFiles\ant\Build\notebook.xml:71:
>   Failed to launch or connect to Mathematica kernel: Connected MathLink
>   program has closed the link, but there might still be data underway.
>
> Total time: 3 seconds

If anyone has any suggestions, please , write!!

Comment: I couldn't get Workbench to work properly as long as I had umlauts in the path. Maybe your path/directory contain non-standard characters.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is intended to be progressively updated as I gain experience with this functionality myself. I assume you are using Wolfram Workbench and the documentation authoring tools it provides.

As the documentation describes, you need to make sure that your package(s) are in a proper directory structure for a Mathematica application. You can do this by initially selecting "Application" for the project type in Workbench. (**File > New > Project**)
[image]

If you already have packages, you need to move them into this structure, at the top level folder for the project. (I have obscured the project name here so as not to identify my employer.)

[image]

Right-click/control-click on one of the subfolders in the documentation folder tree, and choose **New > Notebook File**.

[image]

Once created you can right-click on that file to open in Mathematica. When Mathematica is launched in this way, it will include in the **Pallettes** menu an item for **Documentation Tools**.

[image]

From this you can click on the **Utilities button** to reveal the **Generate Function Pages** button. Clicking this will generate fresh documentation pages for *all* the functions and options defined in your package. It is also clever enough to trace through if your main package calls other custom packages and creates documentation for those objects as well. My current project has around 60 new functions and options; it took about three minutes to create all the pages.

**However, for this to work well, it is essential that you have already defined good usage messages for all your functions and options defined in your packages. Usage messages have to start with the name of the function to be recognised properly:** see the example in the screenshot below.

[image]

The pages themselves come out looking like this:

[image]

Obviously, in this instance, my `DateListBarChart` function builds on existing functionality and takes all the options that `BarChart` does.

If you scroll down these pages, you will find that they have sections designed specifically for examples that you can provide, and that the user can interact with.

[image]

To get the documentation into final form, you need to click the **Build** button in the **Application Tools** tab of Workbench’s **Mathematica Development** perspective. You can then click **Deploy Application** in the same tab to get package and bundle into a place on the `$Path` that Mathematica can find when it is running normally rather than in conjunction with Workbench.

[image]

Most of this information is in the Workbench documentation, but to be honest it isn’t particularly clear. The tip about making sure you have sensible usage messages wasn’t anywhere that I could find.

Comment: I noticed when creating documentation with this tool that copying examples from the example pages available from the Author palette for each kind of available document type (Symbol,Guide,Tutorial) is usually faster than adding new elements with buttons from the Author palette.

Comment: @Verbeia I followed your steps but got BUILD FAILED: /Users/admin/Documents/workspace/test/docbuild.xml:90: taskdef A class needed by class com.wolfram.jlink.util.MathematicaTask cannot be found: org/apache/tools/ant/Task
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Wolfram Workbench 2](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) and its documentation. They demonstrate how to set up help pages similar to the built in ones.